# What game is this shot from?

Tags: game-identification

This looks like it might be from a newer RPG, but I can't find anything online about a specific game. Google Image Search tells me nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's not from a game. It appears to be concept art, for nothing in particular

[Slightly NSFW Game Concept Art Site](https://www.artstation.com/artist/matthiasdemuylder)